# open subset of locally compact is also locally compact?

Tags: real-analysis

If X is locally compact Hausdorff and U is an open subset of X, then U is also  locally compact. Is this correct? My definition of locally compact is X is locally compact if every point of X has a neighborhood whose closure is compact.

I know there is the same question in this website. But the answers of the question either use the definition that is different from mine or use the notion that I don't learn. I don't learn regular space.

Comment: Does locally compact include Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes, X is locally compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @PaulFrost Can you help me?  the answers of the question either use the definition that is different from mine or use the notion that I don't learn. I don't learn regular space.